# Updating query one by one

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to recover deleted rows by selecting rows in this picture, there are 3 records, so I deleted the 2

[image: in this picture, there are 3 records, so I deleted the 2]

they will then show up here in the archive

[image: they will then show up here in the archive]

but when I try to recover, instead of one by one, they will be recovered instantly. as it loads, the recovered records will then be back to the first picture]

[image: as it loads, the recovered records will then be back to the first picture] which is the first 1 and this is my code for the recover:

```vb
Private Sub Recover_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Recover.Click
        Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE [EmmeSubic].[dbo].[UserDetails] SET isDeleted = NULL where isDeleted = 1", conn)
            ' command.Parameters.Add("@user_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Driverlist.tbxUser_id.Text
            conn.Open()
            If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to recover?", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DeletedUserTable.SelectedRows
                    DeletedUserTable.Rows.Remove(row)
                Next
                MessageBox.Show("The User is successfully Recovered!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                conn.Close()
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. However, you seem not to have asked a question or even really described a problem. Precisely what do you need help with?

Comment: Condolences to anyone who has to actually use that UI on day to day basis.

Comment: Now is good time to start implementing best practices. All of that very, VERY personal information (or at least some of it) should be encrypted.

Comment: i am trying to recover the selected row by clicking the recover button(which means there should only be one at a time). however, it seem that whenver I click it, the 2 deleted is being recovered. sorry for the UI. I am new to these kinds of things thats why I am having a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE [EmmeSubic].[dbo].[UserDetails] SET isDeleted = NULL where isDeleted = 1` undeletes every record that was ever deleted. You need to also specify the according ID.

Your query has several other issues:

I personally would *never* include the database name in a query. Doing so prevents you from running your application against a test or integration database with different database name, which I *always* recommend to do - that way the database knows whether it is the production one or not even after copying the productional database over the test database. Why would the database care? There could be different behaviors in sending mails, different path definitions for imports and exports to other systems etc.).

Why is the deleted flag NULL when not set and not 0? In my humble opinion, it should be defined NOT NULL and be defaulting to 0.

Comment: You can have the same database name on a different instance of SQL Server. I agree that hardcoding the database name into the application is a bad idea, but it's just as bad to not have your test database on a different server.

Comment: @alroc Why is it bad to not have your test db on a different server?

Comment: Security, performance, and change isolation. How can you test that an OS or SQL Server patch won't have negative effects on your production code if test lives on the same server as production? If someone writes a query against test that consumes large amounts of resources, how do you ensure that it won't bring production down?

Comment: @alroc: Of course you have the test databases on different servers/clusters, I just recommend to also use different database names. But one can also query the server name, that's true. There just should not be any manual intervention after copying the productional database onto a test environment as at one point in time someone forgets to adjust the IsTest flag or the like and then chaos occurs.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. and I am sorry. I am new to this kind of things. I include the dbase name because whenever I dont I am getting an error saying that what I have entered is an invalid object name. where in fact I only remove the emme subic and just stick dbo.userdetails to it. Sorry if I cause such question. I wont bother anyone again.

Comment: @Kenneth Castro: You have to include the database in the connection string, e.g. ```Initial Catalog=EmmeSubic``` or ```Database=EmmeSubic``` (does the same, just 2 different syntaxes).